# Xslt, Xpath group child nodes by a pair of two

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:
(The paper child could be any name of a node I do not know at this stage)

```
<catalog>
    <Paper result="false">Paper1</Paper>
    <Books result="true">Books1</Books>
    <Books result="true">Books2</Books>
    <Books result="true">Books3</Books>
    <Books result="true">Books4</Books>
    <Paper result="false">Paper2</Paper>
    <Books result="false">Books5</Books>
    <Paper result="false">Paper3</Paper>
    <Books result="true">Books6</Books>
    <Books result="true">Books7</Books>
    <Books result="false">Books8</Books>
    <Paper result="false">Paper4</Paper>
    <Paper result="false">Paper5</Paper>
    <Books result="true">Books9</Books>
    <Books result="true">Books10</Books>
    <Books result="true">Books11</Books>
    <Books result="true">Books12</Books>
    <Books result="true">Books13</Books>
    <Books result="true">Books14</Books>
    <Books result="false">Books15</Books>
</catalog>
```

I try to group the books on a pair of two.
In the XML you see the expected result of the required Xpath.

My Xslt (1.0) so far is a bit to large and not really working:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <th>RESULT</th>
        </tr>

        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/child::*">
          <tr>
            <td>

              <xsl:value-of select="."/> | 
              <xsl:value-of select="@result"/> =

              <xsl:value-of select="( self::Books and following-sibling::*[1][self::Books] ) or
( self::Books and preceding-sibling::*[1][self::Books] and not( following-sibling::*[1][self::Books] ) and not( preceding-sibling::*[position()=2][self::Books] ) ) or
( self::Books and preceding-sibling::*[1][self::Books] and preceding-sibling::*[position()=1][self::Books] and preceding-sibling::*[position()=2][self::Books]  and preceding-sibling::*[position()=3][self::Books]  ) " />

            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Xpath (1.0) logic is to static and needs to be more flexible in terms of the amount of books.

**Result:**

```
Paper1  | false = false
Books1  | true  = true
Books2  | true  = true
Books3  | true  = true
Books4  | true  = true
Paper2  | false = false
Books5  | false = false
Paper3  | false = false
Books6  | true  = true
Books7  | true  = true
Books8  | false = false
Paper4  | false = false
Paper5  | false = false
Books9  | true  = true
Books10 | true  = true
Books11 | true  = true
Books12 | true  = true
Books13 | true  = true
Books14 | true  = true
Books15 | false = true
```

As you can see the result of Books15 is not as expected.

I can extend my logic and add also the case for 7+ Books but this is not a good approach.

Another approach was to count the preceding Books and check them against mod 2 to see if the number is even. Therefore I know if the current Books can be grouped with the previous one or not. However, I am struggling to get the count in between Books and the other child nodes working as I do not know the name nor the value of the other child nodes.

Anyone has a good approach to group n child nodes in a pair of two?

As I am working in a limited environment of XSLT, I cannot use keys or can change the foreach as it needs to iterate through all child nodes I do not know.

Help is much appreciated.

Cheers

**UPDATE**

I am sorry, I thought my explanation was enough to solve the main problem so I can work out the rest by myself. Anyway, the desired end-result output of the XML should be the following:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Paper1</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>Books1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Books2</td></tr>
</table>    

<table>
  <tr><td>Books3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Books4</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>Paper2</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>Books5</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>Paper3</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>Books6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Books7</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>Books8</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>Paper4</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>Books9</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Books10</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>Books11</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Books12</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>Books13</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Books14</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>Books15</td></tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, the books are grouped together by a pair of two as long as there are a possible "candidate" to group with. Books5, Books8 and Books15 are alone as there is no direct Books child above or below which met the criteria of the grouping as there is another child in between.

Again, I do not know what the other child nodes are (Paper in that case) so I cannot use the name, attribute nor content of them to match with.

Comment: Could you try and explain what exactly are you trying to accomplish here? The non-working code and the incorrect result are not sufficient to understand what needs to be done.

Comment: Updated my question with the desired result - sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not as trivial as I mistakenly thought at first. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="grpOfBooks" match="Books" use="count(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::Books)])" />

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catalog/*[not(self::Books)]">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="Books [count(. | key('grpOfBooks', count(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::Books)]))[1]) = 1]">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('grpOfBooks',count(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::Books)]))[position() mod 2 = 1] ">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::Books]">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Books[1]"/></td>
                    </xsl:if>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Books"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

Here's the same thing, implemented (less efficiently!) without using a key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catalog/*[not(self::Books)]">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="Books[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::Books])]">
    <xsl:variable name="grp" select="count(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::Books)])" />
    <xsl:for-each select="(. | following-sibling::Books) [count(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::Books)])=$grp] [position() mod 2 = 1] ">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::Books]">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Books[1]"/></td>
                    </xsl:if>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Books"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hey Michael, thank you for your example. It is generating the correct result and it seems to work. Unfortunately, as I wrote in my question, I cannot use keys as I am in a very limited XSLT environment. You would save my day if you can get the same result without xsl:key. My idea was to count the previous Books until a different child and check if the mod 2 = 1 to see if it is even

Comment: @Talisin Which processor are you using that cannot use keys?

Comment: I think you can achieve this in pure XPath using the Kaysian algorithm. Seems like an interesting challenge :)

Comment: It is not the processor it is a compiler engine which is missing the implementation for xsl:key. As I have no access to the source of the compiler engine, I cannot add this feature to it for now. That said I need to get a logic without using xsl:key and preferred as a xpath statement

Comment: up-vote your answer because it is a working solution with keys - however not working for my case.

Comment: @Talisin See the edit to my post. Didn't think keys would be out of reach to any XSLT implementation in 2014...

Comment: The compiler engine is a bit older and there are other issues need to be solved before adding new features. Anyway, your solution works great and I only need to amend it a bit for the compiler engine! Thank you :)